# 3D animation with OpenGl

Tags: java, opengl-es

I have these two images
this
[image]

and this
[image]

With OpenGl I want to be a result as following
[image]

How can I do that with Blackberry or Android
Thanks a lot

Comment: "Homework like task" + no-code or specific question = poor question.

Answer (score 1):

Reflections are typically done using a stencil buffer. [Here](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/clipping__reflections_using_the_stencil_buffer/17004/) is a tutorial on how the technique works. You won't be able to use the code though, as it is written for a deprecated version of OpenGL which doesn't match OpenGLES, so you'll need to write your own rendering code. Google provides a basic tutorial on how to use OpenGL ES, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you like there is a library that might help you, its called min3d

http://code.google.com/p/min3d/

its very handy, has a lot of examples, and saves a lot of work

Answer (score 1):

If you are actually looking for a 3D engine, [jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.org/) is a scene graph based OpenGL engine with powerful features and good community support. It is platform independent and also supports Android >=2.2